# how to convert a string to json object using jquery

Tags: javascript

```
str = {'8': {'name': 'breeze bedsheet ', 'price': 1150, 'qty': 1, 'strid': '8', 'image': 'images/download_1.jpg'}, '10': {'name': 'neat and clean bedsheet ', 'price': 1150, 'qty': 2, 'strid': '10', 'image': 'images/images_2.jpg'}}
```

obj = JSON.parse(str)

I want to convert this string to JSON object but when i use JSON.parse method it gives me an error like

uncaught syntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1

Comment: There is no reason to parse anything - you already have an object. `str` is not a string at all.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you use `'` instead of `"`

```js
str = "{'8': {'name': 'breeze bedsheet ', 'price': 1150, 'qty': 1, 'strid': '8', 'image': 'images/download_1.jpg'}, '10': {'name': 'neat and clean bedsheet ', 'price': 1150, 'qty': 2, 'strid': '10', 'image': 'images/images_2.jpg'}}";

obj = JSON.parse(str.replaceAll("'", '"'));

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thank you sir, You have solve my problem which i have face for two days thank a lot

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas No problem. Could you turn my awnser into solution please ?